# What is the Windows equivalent of pwd.getpwnam(username).pw_dir?

Tags: python, windows, home-directory

The Python pwd module provides access to `getpwnam(3)` POSIX API, which can be used to get the home directory for a particular user by username, as well determining if the username is valid at all.  `pwd.getpwnam` will raise an exception if called with a non-existent username.

At first it seems like the same result can be achieved in a cross-platform manner via `os.path.expanduser('~username')`.  However, it appears that with Python 2.6 on Windows XP this won't actually produce a failure for a non-existent username.  Furthermore, on Python 2.5 on Windows XP, it seems to fail even for valid users.

Can this information be obtained reliably on Windows?  How?

Comment: Always love a good "Python on Windows" question. The sooner we bring enlightenment to that platform (if it's possible), the better for all.

Comment: `~user` is not supposed to work on 2.5, it is implemented in 2.6+ but in a _broken_ way - see my answer below for working implementation. Yes, had to peek in registry i am afraid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading the [2.6 documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.5/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) shows that `os.path.expanduser()` is broken on Windows:

> On Windows, HOME and USERPROFILE will
>   be used if set, otherwise a
>   combination of HOMEPATH and HOMEDRIVE
>   will be used. An initial *~user* is
>   handled by stripping the last
>   directory component from the created
>   user path derived above.

Say *whaat*? This assumes all user homes have to be under the same parent directory. Nuh-ugh!

It was a bit hard to dig but here is a solution that will look up a local user by given name:

```
from win32security import LookupAccountName, ConvertSidToStringSid
from _winreg import OpenKey, QueryValueEx, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

def getUserDir(userName):
    ssid = ConvertSidToStringSid(LookupAccountName(None, userName)[0])
    key = OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\\' + ssid)
    return QueryValueEx(key, 'ProfileImagePath')[0]
```

Comment: this yields results only for local users?

Comment: This getUserDir looks promising.  I tried it out on my problem but unfortunately immediately ran into a problem where my code is running as a service which apparently isn't mapped to a user (somehow), so one of the calls failed (with an exception complaining about the lack of such a mapping).  For the time being I stopped there, but I'll probably revisit this at some point.  Perhaps once I set up whatever mapping is required, this function will satisfy the requirements.

Comment: @Jean-Paul: ah, this seems entirely another issue. By default win services run under _"built-in security principal"_ `LocalService`, which is sort of a user but may have some limitations (no NetBEUI, no GUI). Optionally you can choose to run a service under another, particular user login. E.g. PostgreSQL runs its daemon under user "postgres".

Comment: The nearest equivalent of `pwd.getpwnam` would be `win32net.NetUserGetInfo` with level 4 inormation. The result includes the user's `home_dir` and roaming `profile` directory. In case they're both empty, it also includes the `user_sid` to look up the local profile directory.

Comment: The problem is that the system has separate concepts of 'profile' and 'home', which, for the current user, are accessed as `%USERPROFILE%` and `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`. The bigger problem is that known user folders (e.g. "Desktop") can be individually set to any local or remote directory instead of the defaults in the profile directory. Determining this requires loading the user's profile registry hive ("ntuser.dat") with `winreg.LoadKey` (backup/restore privilege) and reading values from the user's "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders".

Answer (score 3):

I am new to Windows security... but reading MSDN and some blogs it seems to me that the way MS want us to handle other users specific data is by getting a user token.

There used to be a nice wiki of Keith Brown .Net Developers Guide to Windows Security... you can still find it in Google cache for "pluralsight keith.guidebook"

**Case 1: If you don't have the user password:**

For local accounts you can try reading the Windows registry as Nas Banov already suggested and there are some other recipes on SO or the Internet.

I am not sure how various Windows versions behaves for freshly create users ... those which have never performed an interactive session login ... does it automatically creates their registry, home folder and profile data?
I have done some tests on Windows XP and those registry keys were not present after creating an local account ... but in this case you can try to guess it based in All Users registry values ... or just fail :)

For desktop applications, when the application is running as a logged in user, I am using something like this to get the home folder....  and to get the equivalent of ~/.local I am using CSIDL_APPDATA, for roaming profiles, or just CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA.

```
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon
# See microsoft references for further CSIDL constants
# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181(VS.85).aspx
folder_name = shell.SHGetFolderPath(0, shellcon.CSIDL_PROFILE, 0, 0)
```

Reading Keith Brown article "[How To Get A Token For A User](https://web.archive.org/web/20110224015020/http://alt.pluralsight.com/wiki/default.aspx/Keith.GuideBook/HowToGetATokenForAUser.html)" .. you can look for some other ways of getting an user token without a password...

**Case 2: If you have the user password:**

Reading the MSDN I got the impressing that if I have an user token, I can get its folders by calling something like the code below... but it did not worked for me. (not sure why)

```
token = win32security.LogonUser(
            username,
            None, # we uses UPN format for username
            password,
            win32security.LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK,
            win32security.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
            )
folder_name = shell.SHGetFolderPath(0, shellcon.CSIDL_PROFILE, token, 0)
```

This is why I ended up with this code...which is far from being perfect due to the fact that it requires username and password.

```
token = win32security.LogonUser(
            username,
            None, # Here should be the domain ... or just go with default values
            password,
            win32security.LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK,
            win32security.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
            )
win32security.ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(token)
folder_name = shell.SHGetFolderPath(0, shellcon.CSIDL_PROFILE, 0, 0)
win32security.RevertToSelf()
```

---

This question is somehow related: [How to find the real user home directory using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668909/how-to-find-the-real-user-home-directory-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

you could go the `win32api.GetUserName()` (current user only) or [`win32net.NetUserGetInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370654(VS.85).aspx) (any user on any server, localhost included) route. the latter could be a bit slow since it can take some time to get this information back from the OS.

```
  import win32net

  def userDir(username):
        return win32net.NetUserGetInfo(None, username, 1).get("home_dir")
```

alternatively you could expand the environment variable `USERPROFILE` on windows or `HOME` on unix to get the information about the currently logged in user:

```
  def userDir():
      if os.platform.system() == 'Windows':
          return os.environ['USERPROFILE']
      elif os.platform.system() == 'Linux':
          return os.environ['HOME'] 
      else:
          return None
```

Comment: Won't work - this will return info only for the *current* user. The question is about *any*, 'particular' user.

Comment: @Nas Banov: true, but only for the 2nd part of my answer. win32api.NetUserGetInfo () retrieves the information for ANY user.

Comment: @Akira: Sounds nice but how? `win32net.NetUserGetInfo(None, userName, 4))` returns `'home_dir': u''`, i.e. useless

Comment: @Nas Banov: yes. interesting, isn't it? could be a Windows7 issue?

Comment: @Akira: I doubt issue is win7 related, since i tested on XP. Probably need to RTFM for gory details

Comment: some comments i ve seen online "suggest", that "home_dir" is empty if it is set to the default... still unclear.

Comment: NetUserGetInfo will only retrieve information available in the domain... on in many default installation the home folder is not configured by the domain, but rather by local configurations. To get the home folder for current user I am using SHGetFolderPath or SHGetKnownFolderPath... the main drawback is that it requires to have the username and password.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be only applicable to the current user, but on my (winxp) machine, `os.path.expanduser('~')` returns my home directory.