# Python Code running in windows, can I bypass part of it using "if not win32"

Tags: python, windows, eclipse

I tried running the following python code in Eclipse on Windows but it is showing errors saying `pwd` is not a valid import:

```
import os
import pwd
import socket
pinfo=pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid())
```

Can I use `if not win32` to bypass this part so when it runs on Windows it just jumps at and doesn't create an error?

```
if not win32:
   import os
   import pwd
   import socket
   pinfo=pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid())
else:
   return
```

If yes, what do I need to do to use this `win32` since it's also showing an error saying `undefined variable`?

Comment: you can (most likely) use a `try`/`except` clause -- or you could rely on `os.name` (`if os.name != 'nt'`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [sys.platform](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.platform) for that.

```
if sys.platform != 'win32':
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much. If you don't mind can you illustrate a little more?
like what module I have to import to use this? 
and will this just run by itself and produce no errors, or is there other things i need to add?
Thank you again.

Comment: You should import the `sys` module first. The problem is that if you want your code to actually do something in Windows, you should supply a Windows version as well :) e.g. `if sys.platform == 'win32': (windows code) else: (unix code)`

Comment: Thank you for that follow up. One more question if you can be so kind. If it were you, what kind of Windows code would you use to to the same function as that piece of Unix code? Or maybe some direction I can work on, cause I'm lost. Thanks!

Comment: Look at the links in [Aladdin's response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11215567/78145) to this question.

Answer (score 2):

```
if sys.platform != 'win32':
 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess those 2 questions may have an answer to your question.

[Is there a portable way to get the current username in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842059/is-there-a-portable-way-to-get-the-current-username-in-python)

[What is the Windows equivalent of pwd.getpwnam(username).pw_dir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305787/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-pwd-getpwnamusername-pw-dir)

Answer (score 1):

you can check OS by using

```
import os
if os.name != 'nt':
   # do something
```