# Easy way to get file owner in Windows 7?

Tags: python, file, owner

I need to get the file owner but I don't see a simple way to achieve it.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41280639/how-to-get-the-owner-of-the-file-in-the-windows-7) but didn't work.
Same with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830618/how-to-find-the-owner-of-a-file-or-directory-in-python), not working in Windows.

I used os.path for other file info, but doesn's seem to have anythin related to file owners.

Any hint?

Comment: What do you mean by *GetFileSecurity* didn't work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the Windows equivalent of pwd.getpwnam(username).pw\_dir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305787/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-pwd-getpwnamusername-pw-dir)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in [this url](https://community.foundry.com/discuss/topic/101091/getting-file-owner-on-windows-x64?mode=Post&postID=886094).

```
from win32 import win32security
OwnrSecInfo = win32security.GetFileSecurity(inFilePath,
win32security.OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION)
SecDscp = OwnrSecInfo.GetSecurityDescriptorOwner()
# returns a tuple (u'owner, u'domain)
ownr = win32security.LookupAccountSid(None,SecDscp)
return str(ownr[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830618/how-to-find-the-owner-of-a-file-or-directory-in-python) seems like what you are asking. Could you first check the solution provided there.

As post owner mentions above, [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830618/how-to-find-the-owner-of-a-file-or-directory-in-python) is a solution for UNIX-based systems. It uses the `pwd` module of python, which is not supported for Windows.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305787/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-pwd-getpwnamusername-pw-dir) is an alternative for Windows. I hope that helps.

Comment: I tried that too, but it seems that pwd is for Linux and doesn't work in Windows.

Comment: Don't post (parts of) another answer as an answer. Try marking the question as duplicate instead.

Comment: @CristiFati I'm a big believer in doing things yourself rather than asking someone else to do it.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: True, but I wouldn't mark the question as a duplicate, at least not without some additional info (and now I have the required reputation to close the question instead of just marking it and waiting for other users to do the same). Also some of the "unwritten rules" or practices are not so obvious, especially for new users, so they need to get it from somewhere.