# Celery as daemon task KeyError on os.environ

Tags: django, celery

I'm using celery as daemon with Celeryd and Django over Apache and on a Google Compute Engine machine.

My Celeryd default is config with:

```
CELERYD_USER="myuser-notroot"
CELERYD_GROUP="developers"
```

And I think all the permissions are well set (I suppose). When I boot my system, all connects well, but when I launch a task that does:

```
import os
homedir = os.environ['HOME']
```

I get on log:

```
    homedir = os.environ['HOME']
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
  KeyError: 'HOME'
```

But if I do sudo /etc/init.d/celeryd restart, the problem is solved. Any idea? Maybe some problem with the service launch?

Answer (score 0):

The `HOME` environment variable is usually not defined for all users. Hence, when Celery is started at boot, the variable is not available.

When you relaunch it using `sudo`, environment variables from your user environment are inherited by the Celery process, which explain why it now works (although the `HOME` will be set to **your** homedir).

You should get the `homedir` a different way. See [How to get the home directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028904/how-to-get-the-home-directory-in-python) for an alternative method to retrieve the home directory.