# python dropping privileges, unchanged environment variables (home folder)

Tags: python, environment-variables, sudo, privileges

When I execute the following code as root

```
import os
try:
  if os.getuid() == 0:
    import pwd, grp
    os.setgroups([])
    os.setgid(grp.getgrnam('my_user').gr_gid)
    os.setuid(pwd.getpwnam('my_group').pw_uid)
    os.umask(077)
    print 'dropped privileges successfully'
  else:
    print 'no need to drop privileges'
except:
  print 'unable to drop privileges'

print os.system('ls -lsa ~/')
```

then the last statement prints `ls: cannot open directory /root/: Permission denied`.

The cause is clear, but the question is: What do I need to do so that `~` will expand to `/home/my_user`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028904/how-to-get-the-home-directory-in-python

Comment: @dm03514 I'm not sure if this is points me in the right direction. My problem is that when using matplotlib I get a `RuntimeError: Failed to create /root/.matplotlib; consider setting MPLCONFIGDIR to a writable directory for matplotlib configuration data`. I dislike the idea of setting MPLCONFIGDIR, and would prefer to "convert" my environment to the one which would fully suit / represent my_user.

Comment: os.path.expanduser('~')

Comment: Is there a reason you are running your script as `root`? Can't think of a situation where you'd have to do that when using `matplotlib`.

Comment: Yes, it's a (non-public) server using a privileged port. Upon start it binds to the port, then drops its privileges. When it receives a voicemail, it stores it and uses `subprocess.Popen(['python process_voicemail.py "' + tempfile + '"'], shell=True)` to process the message. It is `process_voicemail.py` which uses matplotlib.

Comment: While looking at a os.environ dump I found `environ: {'USERNAME': 'root', 'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'SUDO_GID': '1000'...` so maybe the problem is that `USERNAME` has not been changed to my_user, while `SUDO_GID` and `SUDO_UID` changed their id's. So this tells me that I'm not dropping the privileges properly. Will check that out now.

Comment: `os.putenv('HOME', '/home/my_user')` solves the issue, but this feels more like a workaround than a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, where I needed root privileges in order to bind to privileged ports, it turned out to be the wrong approach to start the server as root.

Using `authbind` turned out to be the proper solution, so that `sudo python server.py` ended up being `authbind python server.py`.

I've read that `authbind` seems to have some problems with ipv6, more helpful information may be found at [Is there a way for non-root processes to bind to “privileged” ports (<1024) on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413807/is-there-a-way-for-non-root-processes-to-bind-to-privileged-ports-1024-on-l)