# HowTo Read File in Python Interpreter?

Tags: python

HowTo Read File in Python Interpreter?

I want to

`f = open("~/jobs/2014-12-16/output/output.log", "r")`

in Python interactive Shell. How?

Getting:

`IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/jobs/2014-12-16/output/output.log'`

Without path it works if Interpreter started in parent working directory.

Comment: I don't think `~` works here, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028904/how-to-get-the-home-directory-in-python

Answer (score 1):

There's no (well, very little) difference between interactive python and non-interactive python. Your problem is that the file does not exist, as stated in the error message. Python does not automatically expand the `~` character in paths, you have to use the `os.path.expanduser` function for that.

```
f = open(os.path.expanduser("~/jobs/2014-12-16/output/output.log"), "r")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell Python to deference the ~ character via [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser).

```
full_path = os.path.expanduser("~/jobs/2014-12-16/output/output.log")
f = open(full_path, 'r')
```