# Use different paths depending on which computer I run my program

Tags: python

I'm playing with machine learning algorithms. I use my laptop to develop, but when I want to run some more demanding training I use external server.

The problem I have is how to set a path to dataset so I wouldn't have to change it when copying python files from one platform to another. My current approach is to use the same folder structure and use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4028943/4562957) to get home directory path. But since some datasets are quite big they are shared among all users, therefore are not in my home directory. My idea is to have a file in my home that will contain all the necessary paths and will be loaded at the beginning, but I'm not convinced that its the best way. (I use python)

Maybe you have some ideas how to do it better?

Comment: There is no "best way", but this seems very common sense to me...

Comment: I use dictionary with neccessary paths for this

Comment: @koPytok its not really related to my question, but I like the idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical ways to pass runtime configuration to a script are:

1. A configuration file (See https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html)
2. Environment variable (https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ)
3. An argument passed to your script (https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).

Comment: I like the idea with the configuration file, but why not to use json instead?

Comment: Yes, use whatever configuration format you're comfortable with