# Handling usernames in file paths using Python

Tags: python, file, python-standalone

I'm writing a program that I would like to make a stand alone for my company. It works perfectly when I run it from the sublime text shell and I have everything set up to go except one issue that I can't seem to solve; file paths that involve usernames. Does anyone have any suggestion on how to handle this?

An example is
wb.save(r'C:\Users******\Desktop\Excel.xlsx')

I want to make the ****** part either be automatic or an input box.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028904/how-to-get-the-home-directory-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the home directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028904/how-to-get-the-home-directory-in-python)

Comment: Please add details of what you experience when you provide file paths with user names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `os.path.expanduser()` with '~' where you want the home directory:

```
import os
print(os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/Excel.xlsx'))
```

Alternatively use pathlib.Path:

```
from pathlib import Path
print(Path.home() / 'Desktop' / 'Excel.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I posted a follow up in the answers above this. What you suggested worked really well but then another problem presented itself.

Answer (score 0):

os.getlogin() will do

```
import os
path = os.path.join(r'C:\Users',os.getlogin(),'Desktop','Excel.xlsx')
print(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Awesome! Looks like that worked but it presented another error now when I create it as a stand alone.

Wait originally works when I run it from the shell using this code, where EC is expected conditions:

```
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(driver.find_element_by_name('AppBody')))
```

Whenever I run it as a stand alone though I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Stand_Alone_CAS_Automation", line 57, in <module>
NameError: name 'wait' is not defined
[17344] Failed to execute script Stand_Alone_CAS_Automation
```