# How do I open a file in python with a relative path using with open()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to not use an absolute path for my configuration file because I need this deployed in multiple environments, what is my best option here

The Below code is what I have tried and it is not able to find the path, however I am able to cat the file in the same location. I am using Python3.6 on a Redhat server.

```
with open("~/scripts/config.yml", 'r') as ymlfile:
    cfg = yaml.load(ymlfile)
```

I am getting the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/scripts/config.yml'
```

Comment: What you are providing is not a relative path. ``~`` is a shell expansion (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html), not unlike ``$HOME``. You have to do this expansion in Python explicitly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the home directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028904/how-to-get-the-home-directory-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with:

```
import os
path = os.getenv('HOME') + '/scripts/config.yaml'
```

`~` only works in shell, not in a Python string

Comment: Thank you, this method worked for me, thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, `~/path/to/file` is always an absolute path (`~` expands to `$HOME`). To make this substitution in Python, you need to use `os.path.expanduser` such as:

```
with open(os.path.expanduser("~/scripts/config.yml"), 'r') as ymlfile:
    cfg = yaml.load(ymlfile)
```

Comment: An even neater response, thank you, this worked as well