# How to find document directory programatically - Pythyon

Tags: python, directory, path, document

I need to find the default "Document" directory path using programmatically using pyhon

```
import os

print(os.getcwd())
```

I am able to access the current directory by using above code. How do I get the default "`Document`" directory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the home directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028904/how-to-get-the-home-directory-in-python) Once you have the home directory, it's a simple matter of appending the "Documents" directory.

Answer (score 1):

```
os.path.expanduser("~/Documents")
```

This should be able to achieve what you looking for.

For more documentation , you can refer to https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html.