# How to read data from home directory in Python

Tags: python-3.x, environment-variables, home-directory

I am trying to read/get data from a json file. This json file is stored in the project > Requests > request1.json. In a script i am trying to read data from the json file and failing badly. This is the code i'm trying to use to open file in read mode.

Trying to replace(in windows)

```
  f = open('D:\\Test\\projectname\\RequestJson\\request1.json', 'r') with 

  f = open(os.path.expanduser('~user') + "Requests/request1.json", 'r')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the home directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028904/how-to-get-the-home-directory-in-python)

Comment: what exactly do you mean with `user`? Recall that the default disk for user in windows is `C` yet your file is stored in `D`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using current directory path (assuming that is in the project) and appending the remaining static file path:

```
import os
current_dir = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())

path = current_dir + "/RequestJson/request1.json"

with open(path, 'r') as f:
    f.write(data)
```