# How to get all images from Pictures folder in windows 10

Tags: python, path

I am creating one Image Viewer app in python. For that I want to get all the pictures from Pictures folder in windows 10.

As you know that I can get all images from: `C:\Users\user_name\Pictures`

I can use Path module to get all images files from this folder but that program will only work in my pc because I am typing my user name. User name will be different in different Pcs.

So, I want to know which user is logged in windows 10 and get all the images dynamically which can work in all Pcs. I have no idea how to know the user name. Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the home directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028904/how-to-get-the-home-directory-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to use `pathlib.Path.home()` as answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4028943/7793122