# How to specify a directory in Python

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a simple game with pygame, and I want it to eventually be shareable with others. However, my code manually changes the directory of the python file each time, which uses a path. I thought just putting the code in a folder in file explorer would work to change the directory, but it did not, so I used `os.chdir(r'C:\Users\lukep\Downloads\Gladiator')`. This works great on my computer, but it won't on anyone else's. Is there a way to make sure my program is in the same directory as the images I need without making a specific file path? Any help is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: make the pyhton script take the path as an argument. That way the path can be passed when ur running it

Comment: You can also look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/4028943/4983469.

Comment: I use relative paths, i.e., relative to where my main script is. E.g., if my script is in C:/foo/bar then I'll have my images in C:/foo/bar/images and I'll reference these in my script as images/exit.png. If need be, I'll do os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__)) in my script.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to give a definitive answer without seeing your full code, however as a rule of thumb I would say try to make use of relative paths in your code.

Also, this SO question shows how to determine which directory your script is running in:

[How do you properly determine the current script directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718657/how-do-you-properly-determine-the-current-script-directory)

```py
os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making a new system path variable with the respective directory address
`'C:\Users\lukep\Downloads\Gladiator'`.
Go to *System properties* → *Advanced system settings* → *Environment variable* → *Path*  and add new path variable by pasting `'C:\Users\lukep\Downloads\Gladiator'`.