# Python: How to save .mp3 file in 'Download' folder on Android?

Tags: android, python-3.x, path, youtube-dl

I'm making an application, that will convert Youtube video into `.mp3` file using `youtube_dl` module.

```
import youtube_dl

def run():
    video_url = input("please enter youtube video url:")
    video_info = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL().extract_info(
        url = video_url,download=False
    )
    filename = f"{video_info['title']}.mp3"
    options={
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'keepvideo': False,
        'outtmpl': filename,
    }

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(options) as ydl:
        ydl.download([video_info['webpage_url']])

    print("Download complete... {}".format(filename))

if __name__=='__main__':
    run()
```

Well, if I run it and paste a youtube video link, it will download `.mp3` file into the same folder where my `.py` file is. But how can I specify path for Android and let download `.mp3` into user's
`Download` folder?

Comment: I would try a full path for filename to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Your filename should also contain the path, where you want to put it.

```py
    filename = f"/your/path/to/{video_info['title']}.mp3"
```

As your Downloads folder is usually under your home directory, you could first find out your home directory [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028904/what-is-the-correct-cross-platform-way-to-get-the-home-directory-in-python) and then prepend this, plus "/Downloads", to your filename variable.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer! I think that is what I want!