# What is the use of os.getenv("HOME") in QFileDialog creation?

Tags: python, python-3.8

Like I said in the title I don't get what os.getenv("HOME") does in this code. I am following a course on an online site and the tutor was coding an interface with PyQt5 similar to notepad. I searched for an answer but they are a bit too advanced I guess. Also I have no idea what an environment variable is. By the way this is my first question on stack so excuse me for any possible mistakes and insufficient information.

```
def open_file(self):

        file_name=QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"Open File",os.getenv("HOME"))

        with open(file_name[0],"r") as file:
            self.writing_ar.setText(file.read())
```

The function above is connected to a button **self.open** such as `self.open.clicked.connect(self.open_file)`
And **self.writing_ar** is a QTextEdit object

Comment: What part of it don't you understand? Do you know what `os.getenv()` does _in general_, but just not why it's being passed to `getOpenFileName()`? Do you know what an environment variable is at all? Do you know what the `HOME` environment variable is? Right now, we don't know enough about exactly what the point of confusion is to write a focused answer.

Comment: No I am not familiar with environment variables.. And that is the part I can't understand.

Comment: An environment variable is a variable set outside your program, in the environment in which it is running.

Comment: You might start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable

Comment: ...or the relevant POSIX specification https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, which describes specifically `HOME` as well.

Comment: Maybe [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-getenv-method/) will help you

Comment: (in the case of `HOME` specifically, it's the directory name of a user's "home directory", so using it makes your file dialog start in the user's home directory so they're looking at files in their own home directory instead of, potentially, somewhere else on the filesystem).

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Windows does not set a `HOME` environment variable by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of `os.getenv('HOME')`, it's a UNIX-centric way to get the current user's home directory, which is stored as an [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) per [POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html). A typical home directory location is `/Users/yourname` on MacOS, or `/home/yourname` on Linux, or `c:\Users\Your Name` on Windows -- so that's what this code is trying to look up.

The set of environment variables is effectively a key/value store, mapping strings to other strings, that is copied from any program to other processes it starts; they're thus a way to share configuration and other information between programs (though it only shares information down the tree, propagated only on process creation; changes made by a child process are not seen by its parent; and changes to a parent's environment after a child is started are not seen by the child).

If you want something that works reliably even on Windows, consider `os.path.expanduser("~")` instead. Thus, your code might become:

```py
file_name = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,
                                        "Open File",
                                        os.path.expanduser("~"))
```

See also [What is the correct cross-platform way to get the home directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028904/what-is-the-correct-cross-platform-way-to-get-the-home-directory-in-python)

Comment: There is also `pathlib.Path.home()` and its also possible that a user doesn't have a home directory, so the null case needs to be considered.

Answer (score 0):

It basically gets an environment variable for you and cast that onto a python variable.

From the code you shared, there should be a variable defined at the **operating system level** named `HOME`.

In Linux, that can be done with

```
export HOME="something_here"
```

You can check that this variable has actually been defined by typing

```
echo "$HOME"
```

in the terminal.

You can think of the `os.getenv()` method like it "echoes" the value of that argument onto some variable.

Comment: You don't need to explicitly use `export` when changing a preexisting environment variable (if it already had an old value in the environment, the new value gets copied to the environment automatically), so for `HOME` -- like `PATH` -- it's almost never necessary to use `export`.

Comment: (also, `echo $HOME` doesn't tell you if it's an environment variable or a regular unexported shell variable. `HOME` will always be the former unless something very odd happened, but if one runs `foo=bar` and you run `echo "$foo"` it'll have output even though it's not in the environment).

Comment: (and please, `echo "$HOME"`, not `echo $HOME` -- the quotes are important to guarantee correct output; see also [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else))

Comment: (it's also a bit iffy about what you mean by "operating system level" -- environment variables being part of OS configuration is mostly a Windows thing. Yes, HOME is special on UNIX and _is_ set before a user's login account is invoked, but it's unusual in that).

Comment: (or do you mean that it's stored in a block of per-process memory space allocated by the kernel? That's true, but it's also a pretty low-level implementation detail that I wouldn't expect most Python developers to need to know about or otherwise deal with).