# How do I put a variable in a path

Tags: python, syntax, shutil

I'm trying to store a path in a variable. *see below*

```
target = r"C:\Users\User\CodeProjects\WebSafer"
```

However, I need it to be dynamic. Not hardcoded to my username, so I get the login username by doing:

```
val = os.getlogin()
```

So I need to put the variable `val` in the path. But every time I tried doing it I always get a truncating/syntax error. Please help me! Below is the code snippet:

```py
print("No copy found...making a copy\n")

val = os.getlogin()

original = r"C:\*******\********\*******\***\****"
target = r"C:\Users\User\CodeProjects\WebSafer"
shutil.copy(original, target)
```

The "*" are just for privacy reasons, there actually replaced with the right path location to what I'm copying.

What I have tried so far:

```py
target = r"C:\Users\{val}\CodeProjects\WebSafer".format(val = os.getlogin)
target = r"C:\Users\{}\CodeProjects\WebSafer".format(val)
target = rf"C:\Users\{val}\CodeProjects\WebSafer".format(val = os.getlogin)
target = rf"C:\Users\{}\CodeProjects\WebSafer".format(val)
```

Comment: [What is the correct cross-platform way to get the home directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4028943/1518100) then `os.path.join`

Comment: Your first try would work if you *called* `os.getlogin()` (add parentheses).  The second works if `val` is defined correctly.  The last two are just wrong mixing f-strings and `.format`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mix `f` with `.format`, this is working for me:

```py
import os

val = os.getlogin()
print(rf"C:\Users\{val}\CodeProjects\WebSafer")
```

And I think better way is:

```py
import os.path
from pathlib import Path

home = str(Path.home())
print(os.path.join(home, "CodeProjects\WebSafer"))
```

Then if you encounter some error when copying, you need clarify *what you want to copy, copy a file, or a folder, if a folder, should it go to within the dest folder, or overwrite dest folder*?
You may want try different methods such as
`shutil.copy`, `shutil.copytree`, and different parameters.

Comment: if you are using pathlib, `os.path.join()` isn't necessary, you can use: `home = Path.home(); target_path = home / "CodeProjects" / "WebSafer"`

Comment: i want avoid hardcode the path seprator. isn't `os.path.join()` more cross platform?

Comment: pathlib gives you the same 'cross platform' ability as `os.path.join()` .   However, in the current example the "CodeProject\WebSafer" contains a slash and would not be cross platform.

Answer (score 0):

"r" means the string will be treated as raw string so try removing that and using escaped characters `target = "C:\\Users\\{val}\\CodeProjects\\WebSafer".format(val = os.getlogin)`

Comment: then this is the error I get: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\User\\CodeProjects\\WebSafer'

Comment: you should check more https://appdividend.com/2021/07/03/how-to-create-directory-if-not-exist-in-python/ if your destination path is not exist

Answer (score 0):

You can use f-string (to directly enter your variable) and r-string (to enter the path without escape characters like `\`) together.

```
val = os.getlogin() # Returns username
target = fr"C:\Users\{val}\CodeProjects\WebSafer"
```

If you're getting a `No such file or directory` error, it means that the actual file or folder does not exist. Check the actual path to ensure every part (*Your Username*, CodeProjects, Websafer) exists on your computer.

In case you don't know if your user will have that folder on their system, you can use a try-except block to alert the user or to revert to some default folder instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggested solution

```py
❯ ipython
Python 3.11.7 (tags/v3.11.7:fa7a6f2, Dec  4 2023, 19:24:49) [MSC v.1937 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.19.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: from getpass import getuser

In [2]: getuser
Out[2]: <function getpass.getuser()>

In [3]: getuser()
Out[3]: 'kinite'

In [4]: path = rf"C:\Users\User\{getuser()}\WebSafer"

In [5]: path
Out[5]: 'C:\\Users\\User\\kinite\\WebSafer'

In [6]:
```

I know it's a little late, but that's okay
sorry for bad english