# Python: Issue using filename read from an environment variable

Tags: python, string, escaping

I am using `filename = os.environ.get('HIRES_2023_FILE')` to get a filename.  The file is located in the directory of the python executable and I want it always to reside there as the executable will be distributed to different machines/locations.

If I set the environment variable to `HIRES_2023_FILE = 2023_hires.csv` it can't find it.  If I set it to `.\HIRES_2023_FILE = 2023_hires.csv` it's read as `.\\2023_hires.csv`.  I've tried using `str.replace` to no avail, it strips both `\\`.

Can anyone tell me how I can convert that into a correct filename so my `open` reads the file?

Comment: This is on a Windows machine by the way.

Comment: You should require that they set it to an absolute pathname. Otherwise it will be interpreted relative to their current working directory. Or you could assume that it's relative to their home directory. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028904/what-is-a-cross-platform-way-to-get-the-home-directory for how to get their homedir.

Comment: I ended up going this route; seems to be much safer and reliable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pathlib` to manipulate paths [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.WindowsPath). It abstracts away a lot of pain that arises when trying to do string path manipulation.

`filename = pathlib.WindowsPath(os.environ.get('HIRES_2023_FILE'))`

Comment: Thanks.  That worked great locally, but when I built an executable I was still having issues.  I ended doing as Barmar suggested and require the file be in the home directory.

Comment: I don't see how this will solve the problem that it's trying to access the file in the wrong folder.