# Why do I not have a "HOME" environment variable in python?

Tags: python-3.x, environment-variables, operating-system

I'm currently learning my supervisors code for a project I'm doing and he is trying to access the environment variable "HOME" using `os.getenv('HOME')` in an imported script. This, however, does not seem to exist and returns `None` yielding an error. I'm running the program in a jupyter notebook which I started through the command prompt via `python -m jupyter .`. He also has a line `sys.path.insert(1,MODULE_FULL_PATH)` where `MODULE_FULL_PATH` is the full path to the project, which is run before the import that throws the error.

1. I listed all of the environment variables and found that I have a "HOMEPATH" variable which may be what I'm looking for. Could this have to do with our differing operating systems (he uses macOS and I use windows 11)?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a cross-platform way to get the home directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028904/what-is-a-cross-platform-way-to-get-the-home-directory)

Comment: The `HOME` environment variable is a standard variable in unix-like systems, including MacOS that you mentioned. As you've seen, it doesn't exist by default in Windows. See the above link for some ideas on how to get the homedir in a cross-platform way.