# Running Python script as root (with sudo) - what is the username of the effective user?

Tags: python, configuration, root, sudo

I've recently began using ConfigParser() for my python scripts to add some functionality to them for config files. I know how to use it but I have a problem. My script needs to run as the root user, using sudo. The config files are in `~/.config/scriptconfig/` but when you run a script as sudo it temporarily changes users to root, so it doesn't find the config files. What I want to do is get the config file of the **effective** user so it grabs `/home/myuser/.config/scriptconfig/config.cfg` instead of `/root/.config/scriptconfig/config.cfg`, which doesn't exist.

I need the script to be able to run on different machines, not just mine. So I need to get the home directory of the effective user

Here is an example of the code I'm trying to use:

```
import os, ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
homepath = os.path.expanduser("~/")
configpath = homepath + ".config/scriptconfig/config.cfg"
config.read(configpath)
get = config.get('Config', 'Example')
print get
```

It should print the value of `example` from the config file but when ran as sudo, the path is `/home/root` so it doesn't find the config file.

Comment: Are you using `os.getuid()` to get the real user (instead of the effective user) and work out the home directory from that?  Or are you simply using `os.path.expanduser()`?

Comment: I'm using `os.path.expanduser("~/")`. I use `os.getuid()` because the script must be run as root. So it checks to make sure you're root and if you're not it spits an error message and exits.

Comment: @JMariz: Since expand user doesn't work, why are you using it?

Comment: Well lets say I'm the user `myuser2` on a different machine. I want it to be able to run on other peoples computers to. So it needs to find ~/ directory. So it needs to be able to automatically detect the users home directory. But as sudo it can't do that since the user is changed to root.

Comment: Not really. The concept is the same. I just need to find the home path for the effective user, which is what the original question asks.

Comment: Its still the same concept. I need the script to find the effective users home path so it can be run on other peoples machines.

Comment: I don't see why it even needs updating. I just need to get the home directory for the effective user running the script.

Comment: @JMariz: I apologize.  Some of us aren't able to work through all the comments and come up with one set of requirements.  You can refuse to update the question.  In which case, some of us will simply ignore it because it requires too much work to integrated the  thread of comments.

Comment: @JMariz: Thank you.  Now.  Can you also post the code you're using that doesn't work.  I asked why you're using `expanduser()`, since it doesn't work, and I still can't understand what code you're using.  I suspect this is simple, but I can't follow all the back-and-forth very well.  Please post the code which doesn't work.

Comment: Edited. I put the code and what is supposed to happen.

Answer (score 30):

If you run your script with sudo (`sudo myscript.py`) then the environment variable `$USER` will be `root` and the environment variable `$SUDO_USER` will be the name of the user who executed the command `sudo myscript.py`.  This following is simply a clarification of the previous post by Cédric Julien.  Consider the following scenario:

A linux user `bob` is logged into the system and possesses sudo privileges. He writes the following python script named `myscript.py`:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    import os
    print os.getenv("USER")
    print os.getenv("SUDO_USER")
```

He then makes the script executable with `chmod +x myscript.py` and then executes his script with sudo privileges with the command:

`sudo ./myscript.py`

The output of that program will be (using python 2.x.x):

```
    root
    bob
```

If bob runs the program sans sudo privileges with

`./myscript.py`

he will get the following output:

```
    bob
    None
```

Answer (score 7):

if you want to get the user that was logged in before launching the sudo command, it is stored in the SUDO_USER environment variable.

```
import os
sudo_username = os.getenv("SUDO_USER")
home_dir = "/home/" + sudo_username
```

You also have the SUDO_UID and SUDO_GID for the user id and group id.

Comment: macOS: `os.path.expanduser('~'+os.getenv("SUDO_USER"))`

Comment: Often getting the username of the SUDO_USER is not enough and you need the home directory on both Mac and Linux as @Liviu mentions above. In case sudo is not used, you'd want the home directory of the User itself. The solution would be as in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/42750492/796858

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't work.

```
homepath = os.path.expanduser("~/")
```

So don't use it.

You want this.

```
username= os.environ["LOGNAME"]
homepath = os.path.expanduser("~"+username+"/")
```

http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.getlogin

Or perhaps this.

```
 username= pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid())[0]
 homepath = os.path.expanduser("~"+username+"/")
```

Comment: Should be 'homepath = os.path.expanduser("~")'