# How to add user to Linux via Python script?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ubuntu

I've been trying to run Linux terminal commands via a Python script, and I can't seem to do anything with what I've found so far.

This is what I've done so far:

```
import os
import crypt

def addnewuser():

    uname=raw_input("Select Username")
    upass=raw_input("Select Password")

    #The encryption module seems to solve the obvious security leak,
    #but I still don't know whether even the exposed encrypted password is safe or not.
    ucrypt=crypt.crypt(upass,"123")
    os.system("useradd -m -p "+upass+" "+uname)

addnewuser()
```

[This has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190955/how-to-create-a-user-in-linux-using-python), but I can't seem to find a solution, because whenever I run the script, nothing changes when I try to display all user when I'm typing

```
compgen -u
```

on the terminal.

Update 1: I want to make the process secure, and I've found that I can protect the sudo password from being recorded in the terminal history by using the stdout file. How can I write there with python to create users?

Update 2: I have managed to avoid some security leaks by encrypting the user password by using the encryption module in my code. But if the intruder has the encrypted password, isn't it the same thing?

---

The main purpose of this is for me to learn how to develop adminstration tools, preferrably in Python.

---

I use Python 2.7, as well as PythonIDLE, on Ubuntu 16.04.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you run the program as root (`sudo`)?

Comment: I can't seem to find anything on how to run root commands from the script. I've tried to run it both while I was logged as normal and root user, but it doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: `sudo python script.py`...

Comment: I might not have asked correctly; I think i'll edit the question before expecting answers.

Comment: `pip install ansible`

Comment: Coming back to the question, I have to say that the question 's code was destined to become a library for a sysadmin, for an assignment. I needed a way to run the script as sudo internally, instead of requiring the user to have the sysadmin' s password. Later, I added distributed requests to the sysadmin for their password, and keeping the sudo inside the script helped me a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a user in linux using python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3190955/608639), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my application, what I needed was a way to run sudo commands over a python script.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6447942/675721) is basically what I was looking for.

Thanks again for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 0):

One of the very dirty solution is to run

```
os.system("sudo useradd -m -p "+upass+" "+uname)
```

and add to /etc/sudoers

```
user ALL=NOPASSWD: useradd
```

where user is the name of user which runs your script.

**AGAIN IT IS VERY UNSAFE and HIGHLY NOT RECOMENDED**

Comment: I understand that it is unsafe; I'm trying to make it happen for a first milestone.

Comment: There are two big problems: (1) you give the root access to user which run network server; (2) you pass password as command line argument. I would suggest to rethink your application and keep everything inside python.

Comment: For starters, I 'm thinking about using the stdin or stdout (still figuring out which one) to avoid having the sudo pass recorded in the terminal history.

Comment: I've found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385201/confused-about-stdin-stdout-and-stderr) as resource on where to input the sudo password

Comment: you can try to use subprocess module to organize stdin/stdout pipes... but it should **not** work, because I afraid, useradd should read directly from tty device.

Comment: many of the ways that go around most issues use shell scripts. Is there any case shell scripting works better than python?

Where sould I start?

Comment: It is hard to say, I don't know what you are trying to do and what kind of application you are writing. Solution above should work but again it is **very insecure**.