# Find "home directory" in Python?

Tags: python, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find the real user home directory using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668909/how-to-find-the-real-user-home-directory-using-python)
>   [How to get the home directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028904/how-to-get-the-home-directory-in-python)

I want to access `/home/weasel` to read some files from there but I don't want to write the full path of course - so other users can use the script.. how do you know your username or your home dir with python on Linux?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2668909/777186

Comment: This one, too: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4028904/777186

Comment: Should anyone just want the home directory rather than the user directory, you might try finding the user directory (`ud`) and doing this: `hd=os.sep.join(ud.split(os.sep)[:-1])`

Answer (score 149, accepted):

To get the homedir in python, you can use [`os.path.expanduser('~')`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser).

This also works if it's part of a longer path, such as `os.path.expanduser('~/some/directory/file.txt')`. If there is no ~ in the path, the function will return the path unchanged.

So depending on what you want to do it's better than reading `os.environ['HOME']`

The username is available through [`getpass.getuser()`](http://docs.python.org/library/getpass.html#getpass.getuser)

Comment: `os.environ['HOME']` seems more intuitive for me, because I often use `$HOME` in Linux. But could you point out some use cases where using `expanduser` might be more preferable?

Answer (score 25):

The portable way of getting the home directory in Python is using `os.path.expanduser('~')`.