# Is there a way I can use ~ to point to the home directory in file paths in Python?

Tags: python

I seek to automate some tasks with Python (version 3.5, but I am also curious about 2.7) instead of shell scripts. And I would be glad if I could write `"~/myfile.txt"` instead of `/home/me/myfile.txt`. Is this possible?

Comment: `os.path.expanduser(path)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170407/find-home-directory-in-python

Comment: @l'L'l ok I deleted that comment/flag

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `os.path.expanduser("~")`

```
for line in open(os.path.expanduser("~/my_file")):
    print line
```

Docs:

> On Unix and Windows, return the argument with an initial component of ~ or ~user replaced by that user‘s home directory.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser