# Run my Python script at login on linux

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, startup, boot

I have a Python script, and I want it to be autostarted at every login. It's in a linux system. I followed a guide that explains that is enough to create a .desktop file in ~/.config/autostart/*.desktop and write:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=MyApp
Type=Application
Exec=python3 ~/.myapp/myapp
Terminal=false
```

I tried several times to reboot but the program doesn't execute, even if it seems to be active in the list of application of startup in my lxde environment.

Comment: At boot or at login time? login of a specific user or of any user?

Comment: to be more specific, at login time. the login is of a specific or any, doesn't matter. But at the moment I'm trying on a specific user, not root

Comment: Did you try a complete path like `/home/allexj/.myapp/myapp`?  Does this script have x-permissions set?

Comment: I wrote "chmod +x myapp" in terminal and I also tried as you suggested to write "/home/user/.myapp/myapp" instead of "~/.myapp/myapp" but it doesn't work anyway

Comment: Did you see anything enlightening in the X log file (`~/.xsession-errors` or similar)?  Did you try a complete path for the `python3` as well (e. g. `/usr/bin/python3`, look at `type python3` to figure out the path)?

Comment: Is your application GUI based?  Your comment on bakatrouble's answer suggests it isn't.  Then how about putting its start into your shell's login scripts?  That could be either `~/.profile` or `~/.login` or `~/.bash_profile`.  That would mean every login (also from remote via ssh or similar) might trigger this.

Comment: First I was wrong, it worked when I put in the .desktop file "/home/user/.myapp/myapp" instead of "~/.myapp/myapp". Thanks

Comment: is there a way to identify in that user home is the script executing?Because I need to run this script in other computers

Comment: See my answer about using `$HOME` instead of `~`.  Maybe this works, depending on the program reading and interpreting the file you write this in (your window manager or similar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often things like the `~` (tilde) aren't evaluated when placed in a config file.  Try using the complete path instead (`/home/user/…` instead of `~/…`) and see if this works.  If this works, you can try to use `$HOME` instead (`$HOME/…`) to make this more portable and abstract.

Comment: thanks @Alfe it worked. But the try to use $HOME instead of ~ didnt.  
is there a way to identify in what user home is the script executing?

Comment: You could call a bash to do the evaluation for you: `Exec=bash -c $HOME/.myapp/myapp`.  Insert `#!/usr/bin/env python3` as first line in your Python script and make sure it is executable.

Comment: And if you type `$HOME/.myapp/myapp` in a bash shell directly?  does this properly run your app?

Comment: I also tried this before. It tells "no such file or directory", even if the auto completion with Tab key works, so the terminal sees the file

Comment: I found out how to get the home path here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170407/find-home-directory-in-python

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run your script on terminal login, place it to `/etc/profile.d/`

For KDE (at least, KDE 5) you could add applications to autorun in `System Settings > Startup and Shutdown > Autostart` (either `*.desktop` files or scripts), it adds links to `~/.config/autostart`.

Comment: It's probably a windows-based thingy because of the `Terminal=false`.  You wouldn't want to execute this on each ssh login or similar.

Comment: I need to to work just on home directory. Because /etc/ /root/ or something else is with root permissions and it's not what I need

Comment: thanks @bakatrouble but I need a method that I can implement to the code and can be executed directly from the script, and your gui method wouldn't be managed from my script

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding this line `python /home/user/program.py` in your .bashrc file. It will be invoked each time when you login to your system.