# I have scheduled a python file to run in Linux through cron job so only broadcast message is coming but user input is not coming up

Tags: python, cron

```
import sys
import platform
import os
if platform.system() == "Linux":
   cmd= ' sudo wall "System going to shutdown at 5:00 AM UST"'
   os.system(cmd)
print("Type yes/no to snooze the  shutdwon ")
snooze=input('snooze:')
def shutdown():
      if snooze == "yes" :
         delay_time=input("enter delay_time to shutdown:")


         if platform.system()== 'Linux':
            print(" Hello this is Linux os")
            command= 'sudo wall  "System going to shutdown at {} "'.format(delay_time)
            os.system(command)
         
      if platform.system() == "Linux" and snooze == "no": 
         cmd= 'sudo wall "System going to shutdown at 5:00 AM UST"'
         os.system(cmd)
 shutdown()
```

After running through cron job I'm getting  just broadcast message so I need to get user input yes or no to snooze .Please help me.

Comment: If you’re running this through a cron job, then the question is, *what user*?

Comment: This script is running on some other session that cronjob has created.  Perhaps the script is waiting for a user input forever there, or it terminates automatically.  If you want to generate a pop-up message or something, you need to program that specifically.

Comment: yes ,I need to create a pop-up message like yes or no option to  delay the shutdown time .

Comment: Your `cron` does not have access to your current desktop session, and can't even assume that you are logged in. You can try to access `DISPLAY=:0.0` but hardcoding this is brittle and error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

`cron` has no access to the invoking user's terminal, or to your desktop GUI. You will need to refactor your code to get the answer by other means.

But the proper solution here is probably to hook something into your GUI to run periodically when you are logged in to your desktop. How exactly to do that depends on your platform. [Run my Python script at login on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45189029/run-my-python-script-at-login-on-linux) has some hints but Linux desktop environments are a moving target, and you haven't told us which distro and GUI framework you're on.

Answer (score -1):

Alright, I guess you need the function like this

###### change your python script replace`snooze=input('snooze:')` to `snooze=sys.argv[1]` and save the file to test.py

```
import sys
import platform
import os
if platform.system() == "Linux":
   cmd= ' sudo wall "System going to shutdown at 5:00 AM UST"'
   os.system(cmd)
print("Type yes/no to snooze the  shutdwon ")
#snooze=input('snooze:')
snooze=sys.argv[1]
def shutdown():
      if snooze == "yes" :
         # delay_time=input("enter delay_time to shutdown:")
         delay_time=sys.argv[2]



         if platform.system()== 'Linux':
            print(" Hello this is Linux os")
            command= 'sudo wall  "System going to shutdown at {} "'.format(delay_time)
            os.system(command)
         
      if platform.system() == "Linux" and snooze == "no": 
         cmd= 'sudo wall "System going to shutdown at 5:00 AM UST"'
         os.system(cmd)

shutdown()
```

###### edit your crontab command

```
* * * * * python test.py yes 1
```

or just running

```
python test.py yes/no 1
```

Comment: But then you need to remove the old `cron` job and create a new one each time you change your mind about what it should or shouldn't do.

Comment: `sys.argv[0]` is the name of the script; you apparently mean `sys.argv[1]`

Comment: @tripleee Yes That's I mean , Thanks for pointing out

Comment: after using sys.argv[1] and changed cron to python test.py yes/no  still just pop is coming like System going to shutdown at 5:00 AM UST

Comment: You have to similarly refactor that code, but this is basically flawed anyway.

Comment: @hariraj I have updated the example code .

Comment: your updates I have mentioned in existed code still having issue

Comment: Through cronjob I'm not able to see the user input option in command line