# How to select a folder in users directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, terminal

I am new to using terminal in Mac. When I type any python3 command it only checks the users folder on my PC, HOW can I change the directory to open a folder in the users section and check for the .py file there?

Comment: cd to that directory first, before running python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find "home directory" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170407/find-home-directory-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Access the desired path using `cd` command

```
cd path/to/access
```

Then you can run the python command to run the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the folder in which you want to check, you can change the current python directory using: `os.chdir`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir

In that case it doesn't matter from where you're running your python script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **OS** library which comes shipped with Python.
to change the current directory inside the script, you can simply write:

```
import os

os.chdir("newDir/")
```

if you should want to get all directories which are in the user's current location, you can use the method:

```
os.listdir()
```

Hope that helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the command cd to your folder first.