# Getting unicode answer from os.environ?

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables

I would like to call `os.environ['UserProfile']` on my windows system. The value may be unicode, however the `os.environ` dict returns `str` types only, with non-ascii chars converted to question marks.

```
>>> os.environ['UserProfile']
'C:\\Users\\????'
```

How can I get the correct path of `UserProfile` under Windows?

- I'm using Python 2.7.3
- I'm working on Windows 7, but solution must work also on XP, Vista and 8.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for [How to find the real user home directory using python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2668909)

Comment: How's this a duplicate? I looked at the purported duplicate, and the answers, and there's no mention of unicode. Using the alternative lookup may or may not resolve the character set issue (which I _have_ seen mentioned in other questions), but I have no way to tell from the other question.

Comment: @alexis True. I've used the `pywin32` solution there, because it happened to return a unicode output, but now that i think about it again - it's not more than a hack, and should be a proper cross-platform way to do it.