# Python expand user doesn't work over su on Solaris and AIX

Tags: python, solaris, aix, su

My script needs to execute as `root`, and for some tasks as `someuser`, I also need to get `someuser` `$HOME` path, and thats where comes the problem.

For that job (find user home) I'm using `os.path.expanduser`.

As mentioned the script needs to change his user with `su` and run the code to get user home:

## test_home.py

```
from os.path import expanduser

def user_home():
    home = expanduser("~")
    return home

print user_home()
```

The main script calls the **test_home.py** with `su`:

```
# su someuser -c /tmp/test_home.py
/home/someuser
```

Perfectly fine. But for AIX and Solaris the script doesn't get `someuser` `$HOME`, instead, it gets the `root` `$HOME`.

**AIX**: Executing as root

```
su someuser -c /tmp/test_home.py
/
```

**Solaris**:
 Executing as root

```
su someuser -c /tmp/test_home.py
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied
/root
```

I've tested this code on several distros:

1. RedHat
2. SLES
3. HP-UX
4. AIX
5. Solaris
6. Debian

The problem it's only on AIX and Solaris. Does anyone knows why?

## UPDATE

Using login with with `-` or `-l` works, but I can't use `su -` on my script.  Any thoughts on how to overcome this?

I was trying to not use a shell approach like the above but I'm getting out of options

`cat /etc/passwd | grep someuser | cut -d: -f 6`

Comment: I'm surprised it worked on the other systems. To get an environment as though you logged in you want `su -l someuser -c /tmp/test_home.py`. Does that work for you?

Comment: Hi @tdelaney, no, even when you use `-l` to login it doesn't work

Comment: Looking at the [aix docs](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds5/su.htm), it says just a dash (`-`) instead of `-l`. Linux takes both. Other than that, I've no idea what to do.

Comment: @tdelaney, it works with `-` but unfortunetly, I can't use this option on my main script, because it's ansible who does the privilege escalation and it doesn't support login as far as a know

Comment: What 'login' do you mean? Instead of this: `su projects -c 'echo $HOME'` use this: `su - projects -c 'echo $HOME'`

Comment: Or simply: `echo ~someuser`

Comment: It's not clear though why python is mixed into the question. What is your real problem? http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#idm46469134009424

Comment: Why *can't* you use `su - user -c /tmp/test_home.py`?

Comment: @AndrewHenle, the code it's called by Ansible using privilege escalation, it doesn't support "su - "

Comment: What `become_method` are you using?

Comment: @BernardoVale *The main script calls the test_home.py with `su`*  So call **something else** with Ansible using privilege escalation that then calls `su - user -c /tmp/test_home.py`.  You might want to call it something like `shellScriptThatCallsMyPythonScriptWithTheFullEnvironmentOfTheUser.sh`.  And put this inside:  `su - user -c /tmp/test_home.py`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I'm using `become_method: su`

Comment: @AndrewHenle, this will work but it's not the best solution for my problem, because it requires me send `test_home.py` to all servers before I can execute `shellScriptThatCallsMyPythonScriptWithTheFullEnvironmentOfTheUser.sh`

Comment: @OP I think you had a question regarding this "ansible", but instead of asking it, you asked something remotely related, and misled everyone. It's rather annoying, I should say.

Comment: There are a couple answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668909/how-to-find-the-real-user-home-directory-using-python that may help. In a noninteractive setting, environment variables may be wrong or missing, so rather than calling expanduser with a lone `~`;  call it with `~user` or use `pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid()).pw_dir`. Or possibly (I haven't tested this) use `become_method: sudo` and ensure that sudoers has `always_set_home`.

Comment: @BernardoVale *this will work but it's not the best solution for my problem, because it requires me send `test_home.py` to all servers*  You have to send that file to the servers you want to execute it on no matter how you invoke it.

Comment: It won't help your portability, but on Solaris you can use profiles (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1456/rbacref-26.html) and pfexec.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue, after using sudo or su , It was giving root home directory, I fixed with below way:

```
akjha-mn2:~ akjha$ python test1
/Users/akjha
akjha-mn2:~ akjha$ sudo python test1
Password:
/Users/akjha
akjha-mn2:~ akjha$ cat test1
#!/bin/env python
import os
user1=os.getlogin()
home=os.path.expanduser("~{0}".format(user1))
print home
akjha-mn2:~ akjha$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import socket
import os
import time
import sys
import pwd


###############################################################################
# Set uid and gid
###############################################################################

def set_uid_gid( uid, gid ):
    os.setgid(gid)
    os.setuid(uid)
###############################################################################
# Set effective uid and gid
###############################################################################
def set_effective_uid_gid( uid, gid ):
    os.setegid(gid)
    os.seteuid(uid)

###############################################################################
# Get uid and gid
###############################################################################

def get_uid_gid():
    uid = os.getuid()
    gid = os.getgid()
    return( uid, gid )
###############################################################################
def get_euid_egid():
    uid = os.geteuid()
    gid = os.getegid()
    return( uid, gid )

###############################################################################
def get_uid_gid_for_user( username):
    pwd_obj = pwd.getpwnam(username)
    uid = pwd_obj.pw_uid
    gid = pwd_obj.pw_gid
    return( uid, gid)

#Switch to <SOMEUSER>
def switch_user():
    (original_uid , original_gid) = get_uid_gid()
    (analyst_uid , analyst_gid) = get_uid_gid_for_user("<SOMEUSER>")
    set_effective_uid_gid(analyst_uid ,analyst_gid)
    os.system('python run_this_script,py')
    #Switch back to root/original
    set_uid_gid(original_uid , original_gid)
```