# Would os.path.expanduser('~/') return no directory?

Tags: python, path, operating-system, home-directory, expanduser

From [How to get the home directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028904/how-to-get-the-home-directory-in-python) and [How to find the real user home directory using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668909/how-to-find-the-real-user-home-directory-using-python), it's possible to find the user's home directory with:

```
import os
os.path.expanduser('~/')
```

But **would there be a chance that `os.path.expanduser()` can't find anything and returns `~/`?**

I'm asking this question because, from `nltk`, there's this line at https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/downloader.py#L951

```
homedir = os.path.expanduser('~/')
if homedir == '~/':
    raise ValueError("Could not find a default download directory")
```

Note: The question is not asking how to find the user home directory, it's asking whether there's any point in checking for the value of the `os.path.expanduser` and raising an Error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the real user home directory using python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668909/how-to-find-the-real-user-home-directory-using-python)

Comment: Yes, and a `ValueError` is a good thing to `raise` since the code should not proceed further at this point, until such point as there is another strategy used for finding the correct directory.

Answer (score 1):

In the official document.

> On Unix, an initial ~ is replaced by the environment variable HOME if
>   it is set; otherwise the current user’s home directory is looked up in
>   the password directory through the built-in module pwd. An initial
>   ~user is looked up directly in the password directory.
>
> ...
>
> If the
>   expansion fails or if the path does not begin with a tilde, the path
>   is returned unchanged.

So as the document saying, if the operation fails, it will return the original string. And, the point is, return **unchanged** path but not 
constantly `~/`.