# Relative Filepaths in Python

Tags: python, filepath

I have multiple filepaths in my code like such:

```
pd.read_excel(r'..\\..\\folder1 name\\folder2 name\\file.xlsx')
```

If someone else runs this on their computer, will it correctly function, given that they have access to the same filepath? The reason why I am doing this is because the files are on OneDrive. The path is the same for everyone, but everyone has a different user ID at the beginning i.e.

```
(r'userID\\..\\folder1 name\\folder2 name\\file.xlsx')
```

Comment: If `file.xlsx` exists at that relative path and they run the python script from the directory the script is in, then yes. This is the exact reason relative paths are a thing

Comment: Use ```%userprofile%```. Also view this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668909/how-to-find-the-real-user-home-directory-using-python

Comment: @Infinyte7 - True, keeping in mind that syntax is only valid on Win.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Thank you! I only exclusively saw pathlib being suggested in answers, but my above solution seems simple enough to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to use python's `pathlib` (`Python 3.4 or later`) library.

```
from pathlib import Path
base_dir = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
file_path = base_dir.joinpath("folder1 name", "folder2 name", "file.xlsx")

pd.read_excel(file_path)
```

Comment: Is this because it works on other machines besides windows?

Comment: Yes, it will work in different Operating System as well as Windows.